# Navigation bar stop being translucent when self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone

Tags: objective-c, ios7

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I do not want my scrollView to be behind the navigationBar by default. So I set self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;.

That viewDidLoad is the mother viewDidLoad of all my viewController.

That's fine. But I like the translucent effect.

It seems that the translucent effect is gone when I set self.edgesForExtendedLayout to none.

How do I set that to none and still got that translucent effect.

[image]

[image]

I think a good solution would be to arrange the inset of the scrollview.

I did that

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    {
        //self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

Comment: Try this it will not extend your view to below but rest of will extend<br>[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeTop | UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeRight];

Comment: you've marked it answered, is it fixed?

Comment: @JimThio Can you please update the question with the answer? I have the same problem and still can't figure it out. Thanks...

Comment: Your UITableView need to be the main view or it's first subview. Then try not using edgesForExtendedLayout at all. In some view Controller, I just adjust stuff programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translucent means that the content under the bar can be seen through the translucency. By turning off the extended edges, the translucency is still there, simply you cannot see it because there's not content below.

Comment: Is there a way I can still have that translucency effect? Perhaps if the main view doesn't clip subviews on the edges or something.

Comment: Setting clip subviews to false still doesn't get that transparency edge.

Comment: Setting automatically adjust scrollview insets to yes also doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue right now. So if you need to keep translucent navigation bar you should change not edges but insets.
Here is the code, that helps me.

```
if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
      CGRect statusBarViewRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
      float heightPadding = statusBarViewRect.size.height+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

      myContentView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(heightPadding, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the idea. However, I thought self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES; should have accomplished this automatically.

Comment: It's not working for me too, but I don't know why, I may only guess. I suppose that when you're using custom navigation controller or any custom tool to show view controller, adjustment or content insets may not be calculated properly, because iOS considers that your navigation bar is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES
```